# Efficient algorithm for constructing the Edge-Adjacency Matrix

Tags: graphs

I've been recently working with graph, more precisely edge-adjacency matrices. I found [this source](http://www.sicmm.org/~FAMNIT-knjiga/wwwANG/The_Adjancency_Matrix-5.htm), which explains the concept intuitively.

Now, when I am trying to implement this conversion, I was wondering what is the most efficient way to transform a standard (node) adjacency matrix into an edge-adjacency matrix?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know of any way that's better than the "obvious" one: count the edges, build an empty matrix, then iterate through your graph and fill in the new matrix as you go.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I am doing at the moment. I was thinking something in the lines of vectorized expression.

Comment: If the output matrix is stored as a dense matrix (rather than as a sparse matrix), then the trivial algorithm already runs in linear time.

Comment: What about sparse matrix?